# Proper TDD + Dependency Injection in Akka.net

Tags: dependency-injection, akka.net, akka-testkit

I have and Agent, that will read directory X and create child agent for each subdirectory it finds.

To for my testing enviroment I've used System.IO.Abstractions package that creates IFileSystem interface and it's implementation (for normal program use).

Agent (for dir X) uses Autofac DI to create child agents (since we need to give them IFileSystem dependency, and probably much more in the future):

```
var props = Context.DI().Props<DirectoryReader>();
var directoryAgent = Context.ActorOf(props, "DirectoryReader");
```

My tests looks like this:

```
public class DirectoryReaderTests : Akka.TestKit.Xunit2.TestKit 
{
    public DirectoryReaderTests()
        : base(@"akka.loglevel = DEBUG")
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<FileSystem>().As<IFileSystem>();

        var container = builder.Build();  // <--- how do I use this with TestKit
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CreatesAgentForEachSubdirectory()
    {
        EventFilter.Info()
            .Expect(3, () => GetTargetAgent(ExistingDirPath));
    }

    private TestActorRef<DirectoryReader> GetTargetAgent(string path)
    {
        var filesystem = GetMockFileSystem();
        var target = ActorOfAsTestActorRef<DirectoryReader>(
            Props.Create(
                () =>
                    new DirectoryReader(
                        databaser,
                        filesystem.Object
                        )));
        target.Tell(new HashDirectory(path));
        return target;
    }
}
```

Now question is: how do I tell TestKit to actually use my Container for Dependency Injection

Comment: see this one as looks similar for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367570/akkanet-test-kit-issue-when-testing-messges-sent-from-tested-actor